# AppHarbor ASP.NET Google Spreadsheets Hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-web-developer

I have recently created a ASP.NET Website using Visual Web Developer 2010. In my code, I am using these references in order to access Google Spreadsheets:

```
Google.GData.Client
Google.GData.Extensions
Google.GData.Spreadsheets
```

After pushing the project to the AppHarbor website using Git Shell, I am receiving the following errors:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Google.GData.Client". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\temp\orluajnw.mop\input\DVPT\DVPT\DVPT.csproj]
     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Google.GData.Extensions". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\temp\orluajnw.mop\input\DVPT\DVPT\DVPT.csproj]
     C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Google.GData.Spreadsheets". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [D:\temp\orluajnw.mop\input\DVPT\DVPT\DVPT.csproj]
```

How can I prevent these errors and include these references? All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is CopyLocal set to true on those references?

Comment: What does that mean? I am new to Visual Web Developer, although I am fairly fluent in c# and .NET.

Comment: I provided a bit more detail below, in the form of an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may be referencing those dlls from the GAC.
In that case, since they won't be available in AppHarbor's build machine's GAC, you will have to include the dlls inside the code you upload.

One easy way to do it, is to create a *libs* folder (at the same level where your solution is would be a good location), and place all the required dlls there.
Then remove the existing references to those dlls from your current project, and add them again but from that *libs* folder. Also, for each of those references, it may be necessary for you to set the `CopyLocal` property to `True` (if you click on the reference you will see CopyLocal in the Properties Tab below the solution explorer).

More info on Copy Local can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx

That way, AppHarbor will be able to build the code, since it will look for those dlls in that *libs* folder that you have just uploaded along with the rest of the code.